# Finding Fourier series coefficients numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series

Given a known function $f$, I am wondering how fast (depending on $n$) we can numerically approximate the Fourier coefficients $\int_0^1 f(x) e^{2\pi i n x} \, \mathrm{d}x$, either for fixed $n$ or for all $n$ between some bounds $-N$ and $N$. In particular, if there are any tricks (like the FFT) here that would make this faster than an ordinary integration problem.

In particular, can $\int_0^1 f(x) e^{2\pi i n x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ be approximated reasonably well in constant difficulty $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in $n$? Or at least in $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Comment: See *Numerical Recipes In C*, 2nd Ed. (1992), Sec. 13.9, pp. 584-591.  You can access the book electronically: http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html  The algorithm discussed here is much better than a simple FFT approximation.  This algorithm is more in the spirit of a trapezoidal approximation, wherein you evaluate the Fourier integral analytically over each trapezoid.  The result is the FFT times a multiplicative correction, plus some additive correction terms.  Quite useful.  Plus the section makes for good reading.